# How can I create a link to an app in the Mac Appstore?

Tags: mac-appstore

I know how to create a link to an app in the iTunes App Store (iOS apps), but how do you create a similar link to an app in the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works the same as in the iTunes Store:

[image]

Comment: Patrix, thanks for answering. I knew  there had to be an easy way to link..